# How would I constrain a method to only return one of a set of specific values in python?

Tags: python, methods, typing

Is there a pythonic way to constrain the output of a method so that it can only be one of a set? Sort of like typing but for specific values only. I hope you can see what I'm trying to get at with this snippet:

```
class Rule:
    def evaluate(self, user_id: int) -> {"PASS", "FAIL", "ERROR"}:
        ...
```

In the above case I would be hoping for evaluate to only return "PASS", "FAIL" or "ERROR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Commonly `Enum` is used for this. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

```py
from enum import Enum


class Evaluate(Enum):
    PASS = "value1"
    FAIL = "value2"
    ERROR = "value3"


class Rule:
    def evaluate(self, user_id: int) -> Evaluate:
        ...
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 3.8 or higher, you can use [Literal types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
from typing import Literal

class Rule:
    def evaluate(self, user_id: int) -> Literal["PASS", "FAIL", "ERROR"]:
        ...
```